# How can I get the users network login name?

Tags: c#, windows, networking

I'm building a C# application, and I want to identify users by their username. For example, if I logged onto the domain mydomain as the user myusername I'd want to get the mydomain\myusername so I can identify the user.

How can I do this with C#?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's very simple indeed:

```
Environment.UserName
```

From the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx):

> The UserName property provides part of
>   the credentials associated with
>   computer domain names, as returned by
>   the UserDomainName property. This
>   information is typically represented
>   as DOMAIN\username.
>
> This property can be used to identify
>   the current user to the system and
>   application for security or access
>   purposes. It can also be used to
>   customize a particular application for
>   each user.

You can also get the domain name using [`Environment.UserDomainName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname.aspx).

Comment: Environment.UserName doesn't return the domain with it.

Comment: You want to prefix Environment.UserDomainName in that case.

Answer (score 4):

try **User.Identity.Name** or **Environment.UserName**.

EDIT:

Environment.UserDomainName - Domain

Environment.UserName       - UserName

Comment: Environment.UserName doesn't return the domain with it.

Answer (score 2):

`Environment.UserDomainName` will get the [domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname.aspx) and `Environment.UserName` will get the [username](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx).